# Two cloud functions using over 10,000 reads in less than an hour?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I am running two cloud functions. One adds information to posts while another deletes old posts, as such :

```js
exports.reveal = functions.database.ref('/reveals/{postIDthatWasRevealed}/revealed').onUpdate((change, context) => {
const revealedValue = change.after.val()

if (revealedValue === true) {
   var updates = {}
   const postID = context.params.postIDthatWasRevealed
    console.log(postID)
   return admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(postID).get().then(snapshot => {
        const value = snapshot.data()
        console.log(value)
       // console.log(value)
        const posterID = value.posterID
        const posterName = value.posterName
        const profileImage = value.profileImage
        const postKey = value.key
        return admin.database().ref('/convoID/' + postID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
           const convoIDCollection = snapshot.val()
           for (var child in convoIDCollection) {
               const convoID = child

               updates["/conversations/"+convoID+"/information/reciever/Name"] = posterName
               updates["/conversations/"+convoID+"/information/reciever/profileImage"] = profileImage
               updates["/conversations/"+convoID+"/key"] = postKey
           }
        }
           const currentTime = Date.now()
           const addedTime = currentTime + 172800000

           const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
           const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postID)

           batch.update(postFireStoreRef,{"revealedDate": currentTime})
           batch.update(postFireStoreRef,{"timeOfDeletion": addedTime})
           batch.update(postFireStoreRef,{"information": {"posterID":posterID,"posterName":posterName,"profileImage":profileImage} })
           batch.update(postFireStoreRef,{"key":postKey})

           return batch.commit(), admin.database().ref().update(updates)
        })
   })
}
else {
    return null
}
})
```

^That post adds information to a post when it gets enough likes. The posts are stored in firestore, and when a firebase node associated with the post gets enough likes, some information will be downloaded appended to the firestore post entity. In theory, it should not even take one read as the data from the firestore entity is never downloaded, merely modified. The second function running is as follows :

```js
exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub.topic('hourly-tick').onPublish((change,context) => {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const getPostsForDate = admin.firestore().collection('posts').where('timeOfDeletion', '<', currentTime)
    return getPostsForDate.get().then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {}
        const batch = admin.firestore().batch()
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var key = doc.id
            console.log(key)
            const convos =  database().ref('/convoID/' + key).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                 if (snapshot.exists){
                    for (var child in snapshot) {
                        const convoID = child
                        console.log(child+"shit")
                        updates["conversations/" + value] = null
                    }
                 }
             })
             updates["/convoID/"+ key] = null
             updates["/reveals/" + key] = null
             updates["/postDetails/" + key] = null
             const postFireStoreRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(key)
             const posterRef = admin.firestore().collection('posters').doc(key)
             batch.delete(postFireStoreRef)
             batch.delete(posterRef)
        })
        return admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()
})
})
```

Each minute, this queriers firestore for old posts. At most, it may return two to three posts, leading to a few reads. However, after testing these functions out for an hour, the Google App Engine Quota shows *Ten Thousand Reads* while I was expecting close to twenty to fifty. Additionally, the entire day the functions had only been deployed such that they ran only 87 times. Are these functions not optimized? Is there a way to monitor where the read operations are coming from?

Edit : It seems that each time I am triggering the deletion function (actually changing the timestamp of a post such that it will be deleted when the. deletion function is called every minute) my reads increase by a couple of hundred...

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the excessive reads, but shouldn't `return admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()` be `return Promise.all[ admin.database().ref().update(updates), batch.commit()]`?

Comment: @BobSnyder, that makes sense. Still grasping promises currently. Also, the excessive reads have semi-slowed down today, as they are at 1900. Considering one of the functions runs every minute, even if it returns zero results it counts as one query. Thus, in 12 hours I can expect 720 reads. Also, I have been using the app for testing purposes and running the reveal function a couple of times. However, 1900 still seems quite high.

Comment: If your security rules use `get()`, `exists()` or `getAfter()`, those [add to the counts also](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations).

Comment: @BobSnyder  currently no rules are implemented